# Getting local bluetooth address

Tags: c++, c, windows, bluetooth, windows-ce

I am trying to get the Bluetooth address of the local device using the Microsoft Bluetooth stack. I am targetting a Windows CE 6.0 device.

On MSDN I found the following code example :

```
SOCKADDR_BTH sab;
int len = sizeof(sab);
if (0 == getsockname (s, &sab, &len)) {
  wprintf (L"Local Bluetooth device is %04x%08x, server channel = %d\n",
  GET_NAP(sab.btAddr), GET_SAP(sab.btAddr), sab.port);
}
```

At : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee495768(v=winembedded.60).aspx

In this example, s is not declared, so I assume its just a valid socket...

Here is the code I've written based on this example :

```
SOCKET s = socket( AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM );
if( s == INVALID_SOCKET )
{
    return false;
}

SOCKADDR_BTH sab;
int len = sizeof( sab );
if( 0 == getsockname(s, (sockaddr *) & sab, & len ) )
{
    // Use the BT address here
    closesocket( s );
    return true;
}
else
{
    closesocket( s );
    return false;
}
```

I had to cast the `SOCKADDR_BTH *` to a `sockaddr *` since the compiler wouldn't let me compile this, unlike what the example lets think.

This is getting me a 10022 error code indicating that I'm providing an invalid argument, which is not really surprising me due to this weird cast I had to do.

I Also tried another method involving the function `BthReadLocalAddr` which is documented on MSDN at : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms887876.aspx

The function is indeed declared in `Bt_api.h`, but there is no `Btdrt.lib` in the CE 6.0 SDK. However there is a `Btd.lib`, but it doesn't seem to contain the definition of that function since I'm getting an unresolved external link error, which is not surprising.

How can I get this to work ? And maybe find a valid documentation about the MS bluetooth API that doesn't refer to files that do not exist ? Thank you.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to show some basic respect and explain in what way this question wouldn't be legit ? It feels like SO is populated with children...

Comment: Note in the getsockname Remarks section: _Use getsockname to retrieve the server channel allocated to the socket_ **by a call to bind**... so the socket must be bound to a local interface at the time getsockname is called